# Java MultiChoice, 2 false answers?

Tags: java, class

> Which one of the following is false about classes and inheritance in Java?
>
> a) The sub class can have a method with the same name as the super class.
>   b) A sub class can inherit from only one super class by using the keyword “implements”.
>   c) In Java, classes can be derived from other classes, in order to create more complex relationships.
>   d) A sub class cannot have more attributes than its super class.

My guess is d but b also seems false. 
Can a super class be called an interface? I thought a sub class "extends" a super class and a class "implements" an interface. So why is "implements" used in the question?

I'm also having trouble with this question.

> Which of the following is correct terminology about inheritance in Java?
>
> A) We extend from a base class and implement a subclass
>   B) We implement a base class and extend from an interface
>   C) We extend from a subclass and implement a base class
>   D) We implement from a subclass and extend an interface

My guess is C yet it's just an educated guess. An explanation would be great!

Thank you

Comment: I would recommend reading a java book or else perhaps try google.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are not classes. A sub class can have more attributes, It is really natural. Imagine super class `Person` and sub class `Student extends Person`. Should `Student` has less attrituttes than `Person`?